# Go to URL with value from input box

Tags: php

I'm trying to build a search query in PHP and having some trouble.

I need to have an input box which will result in the value of **XXXX**.

Upon pressing the search button I need the browser to redirect to the URL catalogsearch/advanced/result/?name=**XXXX**

I know this is probably very simple question but if anyone can help that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<form action="catalogsearch/advanced/result" method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Use a simple form?

This will automatically append the `"?name=<value_from_input>"` on to the URL and move along to the desired page.

On the server-side, and assuming this is either a url rewrite or a destination page, you'll be able to access the variable using:

```
<?php
  // other code
  $search_value = $_GET['name'];
  // other code
```

Comment: Thanks Brad, works perfectly... was trying to make things too complicated!

Comment: @VincePetit: Sometimes simple is better. ;-) Glad to hear it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is set your form method to get.

```
<form action="yourscript.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="woot" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define `method="get"`

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Might need action="/catalogsearch/advanced/result/" on the form tag if the form is on a different URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the form using GET but if you want to have control over the process and maybe want to log, do it like this:

```
header("Location: http://example.com/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?name=XXXX");
die();
```

Comment: Don't use die() just use exit.

Comment: @Cfreak: why? is there any reason for that?

Comment: die = your program failed due to an error. exit = your program ended successfully

Comment: who's convention is this? your? never heard of that.

Comment: Um. No that would be PHP, and they borrowed it from Perl. Probably based on that fact that "die" is generally considered a bad thing.

Comment: Ok :) But from the plain technical view, `die` and `exit` are the same, aren't they?

Answer (score 0):

Um...

All you really need is in the generic [forms](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp) tutorials.

You are specifically looking for a form with a method of 'GET' and the $_GET variable in PHP

Comment: My fault on that one, I wrote action not method.